# Error Get Data SQL from controller PHP CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

i getting data sql from controller and here is my code

```
$qr = $this->db->query("select journalDetail.JOURNAL_ID, JOURNAL_TYPE_CODE, JOURNAL_NUMBER, JOURNAL_MEMO, COA_CODE, JOURNAL_DETAIL_DESC, CURRECY_ID, JOURNAL_DETAIL_ORIG, JOURNAL_DETAIL_SUM, JOURNAL_DETAIL_TYPE, date_format(JOURNAL_DATE,'%d %M %Y') AS DATE, from t_journal_detail journalDetail left join t_journal journal on journalDetail.journal_id=journal.journal_id where JOURNAL_DETAIL_ID = '".$journalDetailId."'");
    $gen = $qr->result();
```

But my code was Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from t_journal where JOURNAL_ID = '83'' at line 1

select JOURNAL_NUMBER, JOURNAL_MEMO, date_format(JOURNAL_DATE,'%d %M %Y') AS DATE, from t_journal where JOURNAL_ID = '83'

Please i need help i don't know to fix this syntax

Comment: Please use proper tagging for your question: it is in no way related to PHP or CI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a comma (,) before the from keyword: and after 'AS DATE'-

> date_format(JOURNAL_DATE,'%d %M %Y') AS DATE, from t_journal_detail

Remove the comma and I think your problem will be solved.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You are welcome.